# Select name of multiple person using single query

Tags: sqlplus

I have two table TABL_CODES for codes  and  TABL_NAMES for names
TABL_CODES contains

```
Slno Code
1    100
2    101
```

TABL_NAMES contains

```
 Code Names
    100    ABC
    101    XYZ
```

Here i need to select two names in a single query

```
select a.names name1,b.names name2 from TABL_NAMES A,TABL_NAMES B where a.code=100 and b.code=101
```

here i am getting results having both names corresponding their codes.
but i am getting "no rows" if table have a null value when using same query

```
Code Names
   100  ABC
```

how to solve this .thanks inadvance

Comment: What is the output that you want?

Comment: My input code is 100 and 101 .if table contains 100,101 iwant ABC and XYZ.if table contains 100 only i want ABC only

Comment: That response makes no sense at all.

Comment: if where clause encounters null then anything compared with null is null. So make b.code=IsNull(101,b.code)

Comment: `but i am getting "no rows" if table have a null value` - could you elaborate it? Like which table has a null value..

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
select a.names name1,b.names name2 from TABL_NAMES A,TABL_NAMES B where a.code(+)=100 and b.code(+)=101
```